# Mysql dead lock

Tags: mysql, deadlock

I received the following deadlock log via "SHOW INNODB STATUS". Can someone care to explain why the transaction was aborted? It seems that Transaction 2 is holding the lock, but is also stuck requesting the same lock (except for the "waiting" part), which leads to a deadlock when Transaction 1 requires it as well.

```html
=====================================
160518  9:29:18 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 39 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 14132958 1_second, 14132775 sleeps, 1413295 10_second, 0 background, 0 flush
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 14721316
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 2455151257, signal count 47654067916
Mutex spin waits 37909510994, rounds 80118534301, OS waits 733633655
RW-shared spins 4793233766, rounds 33266305107, OS waits 530484103
RW-excl spins 1634009439, rounds 138067494036, OS waits 1055576032
Spin rounds per wait: 2.11 mutex, 6.94 RW-shared, 84.50 RW-excl


------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
160518  8:30:02
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION BBAB5EDD04, ACTIVE 2 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 16 lock struct(s), heap size 3112, 593 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 28455422311, OS thread handle 0x2b5ea7185700, query id 173542708853 ip-10-106-12-151.eu-west-1.compute.internal 10.106.12.151 jquery Updating
UPDATE `tests` SET `startOnDate` = 0 WHERE 1463560200 >= `startOnDate` AND `startOnDate` > 0
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 17891 page no 28 n bits 112 index `PRIMARY` of table `jquery`.`tests` trx id BBAB5EDD04 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 12 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 41; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80001755; asc    U;;
 1: len 6; hex 00971913ed3b; asc      ;;;
 2: len 7; hex 5b000b22292a84; asc [  ")* ;;
 3: len 10; hex 555053454c4c20504843; asc UPSELL PHC;;
 4: len 4; hex 80000032; asc    2;;
 5: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;;
 6: len 4; hex 800004f0; asc     ;;
 7: len 30; hex 687474703a2f2f7777772e70686f746f626f782e66722f73686f702f7570; asc http://www.photobox.fr/shop/up; (total 73 bytes);
 8: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;;
 9: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 10: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 11: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 12: len 21; hex 63686c6f652e6d61756d6f6e742c61726368697665; asc chloe.maumont,archive;;
 13: len 30; hex 393762306638373331353864363932343966323161373639656262396537; asc 97b0f873158d69249f21a769ebb9e7; (total 32 bytes);
 14: len 4; hex d65f392a; asc  _9*;;
 15: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 16: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
 17: len 30; hex 3c70207374796c653d22666f6e742d66616d696c793a20617269616c3b20; asc <p style="font-family: arial; ; (total 1293 bytes);
 18: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
 19: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 20: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 21: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 22: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 23: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 24: len 6; hex 2b30313a3030; asc +01:00;;
 25: len 4; hex 50a512fa; asc P   ;;
 26: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 27: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
 28: len 1; hex 30; asc 0;;
 29: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 30: len 4; hex 8000acfa; asc     ;;
 31: len 8; hex 8000124ccfebfb26; asc    L   &;;
 32: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 33: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
 34: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 35: SQL NULL;
 36: SQL NULL;
 37: len 8; hex 8000000000000000; asc         ;;
 38: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;;
 39: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;;
 40: SQL NULL;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION BBAB5F26FB, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 4, locked 4
38 lock struct(s), heap size 6960, 245 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 28455422293, OS thread handle 0x2b5e98df0700, query id 173542733376 ip-10-106-12-151.eu-west-1.compute.internal 10.106.12.151 jquery Sending data
INSERT IGNORE INTO `accounts_goals_patterns` (`accID`,`condType`,`condition`) SELECT (SELECT clientID FROM tests WHERE id = (SELECT testID 
FROM goals_multiurl WHERE id = t1.goalMultiurlID))
 AS accID, goalTypeID, `condition` FROM goals_multiurl_conditions AS t1 group by accID, goalTypeID, `condition`
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 17891 page no 28 n bits 112 index `PRIMARY` of table `jquery`.`tests` trx id BBAB5F26FB lock mode S locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 12 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 41; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80001755; asc    U;;
 1: len 6; hex 00971913ed3b; asc      ;;;
 2: len 7; hex 5b000b22292a84; asc [  ")* ;;
 3: len 10; hex 555053454c4c20504843; asc UPSELL PHC;;
 4: len 4; hex 80000032; asc    2;;
 5: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;;
 6: len 4; hex 800004f0; asc     ;;
 7: len 30; hex 687474703a2f2f7777772e70686f746f626f782e66722f73686f702f7570; asc http://www.photobox.fr/shop/up; (total 73 bytes);
 8: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;;
 9: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 10: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 11: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 12: len 21; hex 63686c6f652e6d61756d6f6e742c61726368697665; asc chloe.maumont,archive;;
 13: len 30; hex 393762306638373331353864363932343966323161373639656262396537; asc 97b0f873158d69249f21a769ebb9e7; (total 32 bytes);
 14: len 4; hex d65f392a; asc  _9*;;
 15: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 16: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
 17: len 30; hex 3c70207374796c653d22666f6e742d66616d696c793a20617269616c3b20; asc <p style="font-family: arial; ; (total 1293 bytes);
 18: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
 19: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 20: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 21: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 22: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 23: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 24: len 6; hex 2b30313a3030; asc +01:00;;
 25: len 4; hex 50a512fa; asc P   ;;
 26: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 27: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
 28: len 1; hex 30; asc 0;;
 29: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 30: len 4; hex 8000acfa; asc     ;;
 31: len 8; hex 8000124ccfebfb26; asc    L   &;;
 32: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 33: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
 34: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 35: SQL NULL;
 36: SQL NULL;
 37: len 8; hex 8000000000000000; asc         ;;
 38: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;;
 39: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;;
 40: SQL NULL;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 17891 page no 11 n bits 136 index `PRIMARY` of table `jquery`.`tests` trx id BBAB5F26FB lock mode S locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 4 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 41; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 800000ed; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 0097190dd1cc; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex 47000af2930e49; asc G     I;;
 3: len 18; hex 7777772e6c6977696f2e636f6d2f7474276b; asc www.liwio.com/tt'k;;
 4: len 4; hex 80000053; asc    S;;
 5: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;;
 6: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 7: len 23; hex 687474703a2f2f7777772e6c6977696f2e636f6d2f7474; asc http://www.liwio.com/tt;;
 8: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;;
 9: len 4; hex 80000002; asc     ;;
 10: len 4; hex 80000007; asc     ;;
 11: len 4; hex 80000004; asc     ;;
 12: len 4; hex 74657374; asc test;;
 13: len 30; hex 353339666435336235396533626231326432303366343561393132656561; asc 539fd53b59e3bb12d203f45a912eea; (total 32 bytes);
 14: len 4; hex d65f3911; asc  _9 ;;
 15: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 16: len 30; hex 0a24282768746d6c3a65712830293e626f64793a65712830293e6469763a; asc  $('html:eq(0)>body:eq(0)>div:; (total 207 bytes);
 17: len 30; hex 3c6272202f3e0a746573743c696d6720616c743d2222207372633d222f69; asc <br /> test<img alt="" src="/i; (total 222 bytes);
 18: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
 19: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 20: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 21: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 22: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 23: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 24: len 6; hex 2b30313a3030; asc +01:00;;
 25: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;;
 26: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 27: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
 28: len 1; hex 30; asc 0;;
 29: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 30: len 4; hex 800000e5; asc     ;;
 31: len 8; hex 8000124a705e8c84; asc    Jp^  ;;
 32: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 33: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
 34: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 35: SQL NULL;
 36: SQL NULL;
 37: len 8; hex 8000000000000000; asc         ;;
 38: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;;
 39: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;;
 40: SQL NULL;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

Comment: This is the show innodb status

Comment: You want to know **why** it happened or how to recover from deadlocks?

Comment: HI @Mjh I want to know why and how we can avoid this situation.Thanks in advacne for your help;

Comment: The *why* is tricky, there's usually many reasons for this, important thing is that you can be notified that a deadlock occurred and that transaction failed because of it. There's only one way to recover from this and it's to repeat the transaction. In your application, you should catch the message from MySQL which tells you that your transaction went bust and in that case you simply repeat it. Good practice is to have code which repeats the transaction a few times (say, 3-4 times) before giving up. Deadlocks aren't a scary thing, so you shouldn't be worried too much.